# Internal Server Error- http://localhost:1080/webTours/home.html

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, internal-server-error, demo, localserver

**Application:** http://localhost:1080/webTours/home.html [I intend to use it for Jmeter testing]

Below error is displayed when I am trying to click on **"sign up now"** link. Kindly help to fix it. Pls note, I have `strawberry-perl-5.30.0.1-64bit.msi` also installed and path is set to the environment.

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to do the correlation for the dynamic parameters like sessionID etc.

Record two scripts using tools like fiddler or LR or any other sniffing tool and compare two scripts to find out dynamic variables required. Then correlate them. For correlation, identify the first occurrence of the variable in the response then extract them using post processor and pass them further below/to all the request that requires it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your [Web Tours Sample Application](https://marketplace.microfocus.com/appdelivery/content/web-tours-sample-application) installation is broken, looking into `MICRO FOCUS SUPPORTED` stanza in the application details you should contact [Micro Focus Support](https://www.microfocus.com/support-and-services/support-login/) or ask the question in [Micro Focus Community Forums](https://community.microfocus.com/).

In the meantime you can use http://blazedemo.com/ page and [Getting Started with JMeter - A Basic Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial/) as the alternative test application for your JMeter training

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting internal server error while sign up (or) accessing administration link then follow the below,

a. close the server from the cmd

b. In the Web Tours 1.0 parent folder, find the file .msi file: strawberry-perl-5.10.1.0

c. Double click on strawberry-perl-5.10.1.0 msi file to install

d. Once it is installed, Now re-start the server (Double click on StartServer.bat file) under WebTours sub-folder

e. Now, Go to link http://localhost:1080/webtours/home.html

f. Click on Sign up (or) administration link

g. Hope you are able to access the Web Tours app in local server now. Thanks! :-)